# user interface design of a page with many buttons

Tags: css

Im very new in design,i have a page contains many buttons and each button shows chart and grid once clicked,the thing is i do not know how to manage to put all these in a single page as you see in the attached screenshot,its really ugly,i would like you professionals tell me the reasonable way of showing these all,

[image: Example´s screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Group similar contents, ie Use card layout for grouping
2. Keep only essential components, ie Focus on important components.
3. Research on google [Admin Portal designs](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=admin%20portal%20design&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHWL_enIN729IN729&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi94Zaf_NnaAhUKPo8KHSqgAXUQsAQIJw&biw=1920&bih=974)
4. Use themes [Themes](https://deliciousthemes.com/34-outstanding-admin-panels-for-your-web-applications/)
5. Use Behance or Dribble to see how others have designed.Take
   inspiration from them.
6. Before stating to implement a website, draw rough layouts/wireframes
   on paper.See how you can position them.
7. When you are sure of the layout, start designing it on photoshop,
   sketch, gimp, figma, lunacy or any designing software.
8. When u are happy with it, start implementing it in HTML

Comment: for the 3rd item you mentioned,i should use css?whats your suggestion?

Comment: iam using kendo ui and jquery and css i do not know if i can implement a Admin portal with these